# Regular string of hex values to binary string

Tags: python, io

I am writing a file-data searching script and want to allow the user to search for a string of hex values (via `argv`). I had to switch from PHP to Python because the maximum value of integers are (too) limited on 32-bit PHP/machines. In PHP I could just do:

```
$SearchValue = pack('H*', $Input);
```

However, in Python there does not seem to be any equivalent for this format character. What are some alternatives for this conversion in Python, if any? The output needs to be a binary string (`b'...'`).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Is it really possible to convert a hex string to binary data through struct.pack? If so, how exactly? I looked but I didn't find anything - did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
3>> import binascii
3>> binascii.unhexlify('deadbeef')
b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
```